# Grilla Editable en Flutter

Tags: flutter, programación-móvil, design

Me gustaría implementar en una aplicación de Flutter una grilla que sea editable tipo [Kendo Grid](https://www.grapecity.com/wijmo/demos/Grid/Overview/react) pero no se realmente que opciones tengo para hacer algo similar que permita edición de datos, filtros, ordenamientos y acciones personalizadas.

Les agradezco de antemano cualquier idea que me puedan dar, si conocen algún Widget con funcionalidades similares o si definitivamente se necesita replantear la idea principal para que se adapte mejor a dispositivo móvil. En caso de ser necesario replantear la interfaz, me podrían indicar si conocen alguna APP que conozcan que implemente algo similar para ver como plantearon resolver dicho problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes revisar el package `data_tables` , desde el siguiente link : https://pub.dev/packages/data_tables

Ejemplo de como usarlo:

```
import 'package:data_tables/data_tables.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'data/dessert.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _rowsPerPage = PaginatedDataTable.defaultRowsPerPage;
  int _sortColumnIndex;
  bool _sortAscending = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _items = _desserts;
    super.initState();
  }

  void _sort<T>(
      Comparable<T> getField(Dessert d), int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
    _items.sort((Dessert a, Dessert b) {
      if (!ascending) {
        final Dessert c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
      }
      final Comparable<T> aValue = getField(a);
      final Comparable<T> bValue = getField(b);
      return Comparable.compare(aValue, bValue);
    });
    setState(() {
      _sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
      _sortAscending = ascending;
    });
  }

  List<Dessert> _items = [];
  int _rowsOffset = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        // appBar: AppBar(
        //   title: const Text('Native Data Table Example'),
        // ),
        body: NativeDataTable.builder(
          rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
          itemCount: _items?.length ?? 0,
          firstRowIndex: _rowsOffset,
          handleNext: () async {
            setState(() {
              _rowsOffset += _rowsPerPage;
            });

            await new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 3));
            setState(() {
              _items += [
                Dessert('New Item 4', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0, 87, 14, 1),
                Dessert('New Item 5', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0, 87, 14, 1),
                Dessert('New Item 6', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0, 87, 14, 1),
              ];
            });
          },
          handlePrevious: () {
            setState(() {
              _rowsOffset -= _rowsPerPage;
            });
          },
          mobileSlivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text("Mobile App Bar"),
            ),
          ],
          itemBuilder: (int index) {
            final Dessert dessert = _items[index];
            return DataRow.byIndex(
                index: index,
                selected: dessert.selected,
                onSelectChanged: (bool value) {
                  if (dessert.selected != value) {
                    setState(() {
                      dessert.selected = value;
                    });
                  }
                },
                cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(Text('${dessert.name}')),
                  DataCell(Text('${dessert.calories}')),
                  DataCell(Text('${dessert.fat.toStringAsFixed(1)}')),
                  DataCell(Text('${dessert.carbs}')),
                  DataCell(Text('${dessert.protein.toStringAsFixed(1)}')),
                  DataCell(Text('${dessert.sodium}')),
                  DataCell(Text('${dessert.calcium}%')),
                  DataCell(Text('${dessert.iron}%')),
                  DataCell(ButtonBar(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _items.remove(dessert);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
                ]);
          },
          header: const Text('Data Management'),
          sortColumnIndex: _sortColumnIndex,
          sortAscending: _sortAscending,
          onRefresh: () async {
            await new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 3));
            setState(() {
              _items = _desserts;
            });
            return null;
          },
          onRowsPerPageChanged: (int value) {
            setState(() {
              _rowsPerPage = value;
            });
            print("New Rows: $value");
          },
          // mobileItemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          //   final i = _desserts[index];
          //   return ListTile(
          //     title: Text(i?.name),
          //   );
          // },
          onSelectAll: (bool value) {
            for (var row in _items) {
              setState(() {
                row.selected = value;
              });
            }
          },
          rowCountApproximate: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
          selectedActions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  for (var item in _items
                      ?.where((d) => d?.selected ?? false)
                      ?.toSet()
                      ?.toList()) {
                    _items.remove(item);
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
          mobileIsLoading: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          noItems: Text("No Items Found"),
          columns: <DataColumn>[
            DataColumn(
                label: const Text('Dessert (100g serving)'),
                onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>(
                    (Dessert d) => d.name, columnIndex, ascending)),
            DataColumn(
                label: const Text('Calories'),
                tooltip:
                    'The total amount of food energy in the given serving size.',
                numeric: true,
                onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>(
                    (Dessert d) => d.calories, columnIndex, ascending)),
            DataColumn(
                label: const Text('Fat (g)'),
                numeric: true,
                onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) =>
                    _sort<num>((Dessert d) => d.fat, columnIndex, ascending)),
            DataColumn(
                label: const Text('Carbs (g)'),
                numeric: true,
                onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) =>
                    _sort<num>((Dessert d) => d.carbs, columnIndex, ascending)),
            DataColumn(
                label: const Text('Protein (g)'),
                numeric: true,
                onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>(
                    (Dessert d) => d.protein, columnIndex, ascending)),
            DataColumn(
                label: const Text('Sodium (mg)'),
                numeric: true,
                onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>(
                    (Dessert d) => d.sodium, columnIndex, ascending)),
            DataColumn(
                label: const Text('Calcium (%)'),
                tooltip:
                    'The amount of calcium as a percentage of the recommended daily amount.',
                numeric: true,
                onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>(
                    (Dessert d) => d.calcium, columnIndex, ascending)),
            DataColumn(
                label: const Text('Iron (%)'),
                numeric: true,
                onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) =>
                    _sort<num>((Dessert d) => d.iron, columnIndex, ascending)),
            DataColumn(
              label: const Text('Actions'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  final List<Dessert> _desserts = <Dessert>[
    Dessert('Frozen yogurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0, 87, 14, 1),
    Dessert('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3, 129, 8, 1),
    Dessert('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0, 337, 6, 7),
    Dessert('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3, 413, 3, 8),
    Dessert('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9, 327, 7, 16),
    Dessert('Jelly bean', 375, 0.0, 94, 0.0, 50, 0, 0),
    Dessert('Lollipop', 392, 0.2, 98, 0.0, 38, 0, 2),
    Dessert('Honeycomb', 408, 3.2, 87, 6.5, 562, 0, 45),
    Dessert('Donut', 452, 25.0, 51, 4.9, 326, 2, 22),
    Dessert('KitKat', 518, 26.0, 65, 7.0, 54, 12, 6),
    Dessert('Frozen yogurt with sugar', 168, 6.0, 26, 4.0, 87, 14, 1),
    Dessert('Ice cream sandwich with sugar', 246, 9.0, 39, 4.3, 129, 8, 1),
    Dessert('Eclair with sugar', 271, 16.0, 26, 6.0, 337, 6, 7),
    Dessert('Cupcake with sugar', 314, 3.7, 69, 4.3, 413, 3, 8),
    Dessert('Gingerbread with sugar', 345, 16.0, 51, 3.9, 327, 7, 16),
    Dessert('Jelly bean with sugar', 364, 0.0, 96, 0.0, 50, 0, 0),
    Dessert('Lollipop with sugar', 401, 0.2, 100, 0.0, 38, 0, 2),
    Dessert('Honeycomb with sugar', 417, 3.2, 89, 6.5, 562, 0, 45),
    Dessert('Donut with sugar', 461, 25.0, 53, 4.9, 326, 2, 22),
    Dessert('KitKat with sugar', 527, 26.0, 67, 7.0, 54, 12, 6),
    Dessert('Frozen yogurt with honey', 223, 6.0, 36, 4.0, 87, 14, 1),
    Dessert('Ice cream sandwich with honey', 301, 9.0, 49, 4.3, 129, 8, 1),
    Dessert('Eclair with honey', 326, 16.0, 36, 6.0, 337, 6, 7),
    Dessert('Cupcake with honey', 369, 3.7, 79, 4.3, 413, 3, 8),
    Dessert('Gingerbread with honey', 420, 16.0, 61, 3.9, 327, 7, 16),
    Dessert('Jelly bean with honey', 439, 0.0, 106, 0.0, 50, 0, 0),
    Dessert('Lollipop with honey', 456, 0.2, 110, 0.0, 38, 0, 2),
    Dessert('Honeycomb with honey', 472, 3.2, 99, 6.5, 562, 0, 45),
    Dessert('Donut with honey', 516, 25.0, 63, 4.9, 326, 2, 22),
    Dessert('KitKat with honey', 582, 26.0, 77, 7.0, 54, 12, 6),
    Dessert('Frozen yogurt with milk', 262, 8.4, 36, 12.0, 194, 44, 1),
    Dessert('Ice cream sandwich with milk', 339, 11.4, 49, 12.3, 236, 38, 1),
    Dessert('Eclair with milk', 365, 18.4, 36, 14.0, 444, 36, 7),
    Dessert('Cupcake with milk', 408, 6.1, 79, 12.3, 520, 33, 8),
    Dessert('Gingerbread with milk', 459, 18.4, 61, 11.9, 434, 37, 16),
    Dessert('Jelly bean with milk', 478, 2.4, 106, 8.0, 157, 30, 0),
    Dessert('Lollipop with milk', 495, 2.6, 110, 8.0, 145, 30, 2),
    Dessert('Honeycomb with milk', 511, 5.6, 99, 14.5, 669, 30, 45),
    Dessert('Donut with milk', 555, 27.4, 63, 12.9, 433, 32, 22),
    Dessert('KitKat with milk', 621, 28.4, 77, 15.0, 161, 42, 6),
    Dessert('Coconut slice and frozen yogurt', 318, 21.0, 31, 5.5, 96, 14, 7),
    Dessert(
        'Coconut slice and ice cream sandwich', 396, 24.0, 44, 5.8, 138, 8, 7),
    Dessert('Coconut slice and eclair', 421, 31.0, 31, 7.5, 346, 6, 13),
    Dessert('Coconut slice and cupcake', 464, 18.7, 74, 5.8, 422, 3, 14),
    Dessert('Coconut slice and gingerbread', 515, 31.0, 56, 5.4, 316, 7, 22),
    Dessert('Coconut slice and jelly bean', 534, 15.0, 101, 1.5, 59, 0, 6),
    Dessert('Coconut slice and lollipop', 551, 15.2, 105, 1.5, 47, 0, 8),
    Dessert('Coconut slice and honeycomb', 567, 18.2, 94, 8.0, 571, 0, 51),
    Dessert('Coconut slice and donut', 611, 40.0, 58, 6.4, 335, 2, 28),
    Dessert('Coconut slice and KitKat', 677, 41.0, 72, 8.5, 63, 12, 12),
  ];
}
```